# Website Scraping In Python Server Detection

Tags: python, web-scraping, socket-timeout-exception

I have come across an interesting phenomenon when scraping a particular site on the web. The issue arises when using Python's urllib2 (Python 2.7).  For example:

```
import urllib2

LINK = "http://www.sample.com/article/1"

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla5.0/...'} # Ellipsis for brevity 

req = urllib2.Request(link, data=None, headers=HEADERS)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=20).read()
```

Here are the strange outcomes:

1) When a valid user agent is passed to the request headers, the server will return a status of 200 and a page saying there was an issue processing the request (invalid html).  This means I am able to get a successful response from the server with corrupted data.

2) When an invalid user agent is passed (empty headers {}), the server will timeout.  However, if the timeout is set to a large value (20 seconds in this example), the server will then return the valid data but in a slow fashion.

This problem arises on the server when there has been no prior requests, therefore I believe the server may be expecting a certain cookie from the request to serve valid data.  Anyone have insight into why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't know what's going-on on the server side.**

You can just keep experiment and guess how it works on the other side. If this is a user agent only issue - just keep sending it(and maybe changing it once in awhile) for ALL of your requests, including the first one.

Also, I would open chrome dev tool on a new session(incognito) and recording all the actions you're doing, this way you can see the structure of the requests that being made by a real browser.

Comment: I agree experimentation is the approach, however doesn't this seem like backwards behavior by the server?  The default user-agent from urllib2 indicates Python and this is when the server sends valid data (although very slowly).  Somehow a spoofed user-agent is detected, and a 200 status with invalid data is returned.  Cannot wrap my mind around this one!

Comment: There is so many old ASP/PHP/deprecated frameworks that use the user-agent for so many reasons. Don't try to understand that, just check what your real browser does and try to mimic that.